# Web OTP API Typescript Typings issue - Missing Types in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, typescript-typings

I am following instructions available on https://web.dev/web-otp/ to implement Web OTP API in my Angular App. But when adding below code it throws error:

```
const content = await window.navigator['credentials'].get({
        otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
        signal: abortController.signal
      });
```

Here's the error message:

```
Error   TS2769  (TS) No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(options?: CredentialRequestOptions): Promise<CredentialType>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ otp: { transport: string[]; }; signal: AbortSignal; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CredentialRequestOptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'otp' does not exist in type 'CredentialRequestOptions'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(options?: CredentialRequestOptions): Promise<Credential>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ otp: { transport: string[]; }; signal: AbortSignal; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CredentialRequestOptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'otp' does not exist in type 'CredentialRequestOptions'.
```

I have `@types/webappsec-credential-management` added, but I believe its not yet updated to support `otp`.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue:

Created a new folder with name `typings` and added it to `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json`

```
"typeRoots": [
      "typings",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
```

Created a new file `polyfills.d.ts` in folder `typings` and added below contents to the file:

```
interface CredentialRequestOptions {
  otp: OTPOptions;
}

interface OTPOptions {
  transport: string[];
}
```

If you are wondering why I havent added other properties to the interface, that's because I already have:

```
"types": [
      "@types/webappsec-credential-management"
    ]
```

And `"@types/webappsec-credential-management": "^0.5.1",` in `packages.json`.

The support of `OTP` is yet to be added, and to addres the missing `otp` property I took benefit of TypeScript's feature [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), now TypeScript compiler merges these two separate declarations (one defined in `node_modules/@types` and other in `typings`) declared with the same name into a single definition.

For further reading: https://justintimecoder.com/how-to-polyfil-missing-types-in-typescript/

**Update**

Below is the function that you can add to your Angular Component to make it work in your app:

```
async otpRequest() {
    if ('OTPCredential' in window) {

      const abortController = new AbortController();
      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        abortController.abort();
      }, 10 * 1000);

      let o: CredentialRequestOptions = {
        otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
        signal: abortController.signal
      };

      const content = await window.navigator['credentials'].get(o);

      //do what ever you want to do with the received code, probably send it to server
    }
  }
```

Call this function, then make http request to send sms code on user's mobile device.

Comment: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AttestationConveyancePreference' in @types/webappsec-credential-management/index.d.ts

Comment: I also get the error 
error TS2322: Type '{ otp: { transport: string[]; }; signal: AbortSignal; }' is not assignable to type 'CredentialRequestOptions'

Answer (score 3):

Add below in global.d.ts file.

```js
  interface CredentialRequestOptions {
        otp?:any;
    }

    interface Credential {
        code?:any;
    }
```