# Web OTP API Property 'code' does not exist on type 'CredentialType'

Tags: angular, typescript, token, one-time-password

I'm trying to implement the solution described in [Web OTP API Typescript Typings issue - Missing Types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411079/web-otp-api-typescript-typings-issue-missing-types-in-typescript), but I get the following error:

```
     Property 'code' does not exist on type 'CredentialType'.
```

could someone help me understand and resolve this issue?

Example:

```
async otpRequest() {
    if ('OTPCredential' in window) {

      const abortController = new AbortController();
      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        abortController.abort();
      }, 10 * 1000);

      let o: CredentialRequestOptions = {
        otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
        signal: abortController.signal
      };

      const content = await navigator['credentials'].get(o);

      // here: Property 'code' does not exist on type 'CredentialType'
      console.log(content.code)
      
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Add more details about what exactly you have tried and possibly some snippets to identify what changes you've made. Stating "I followed this help" will not garner the support you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's seem like type CredentialType is contain only PasswordCredential|FederatedCredential|PublicKeyCredential

due to spec from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/webappsec-credential-management/index.d.ts

and it's missing OTPCredential most likely incomplete need to follow up from DefinitelyTyped, so I workaround temporary by added

```
interface CredentialType {
  code: string
  type: string
}
```

into polyfill.d.ts.

And problem resolved.