# Why the WebOTP doesn't work with typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am working with ViteJs and trying to add the autofill feature for OTP in the web, for that I have used this code to `useEffect` function, for store the OTP code in state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if ('OTPCredential' in window) {
      const ac = new AbortController();

      navigator.credentials
        .get({
          otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
          signal: ac.signal,
        })
        .then((otp: any) => {
          setState(otp.code);
          ac.abort();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          ac.abort();
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  });
```

and I also used the formatted message, What I used is

```
Your OTP is: 7825

@githubUserName.github.io/app-setup/ #7825
```

but it didn't work. then I tried the same approach with `create-react-app` without typescript, then it worked.
For typescript, I did add the `typings` folder and within, I did create `polyfills.d.ts` and linked this folder to the `tsconfig.json` file.

Can someone help me out, please what I am missing to do?

Comment: typescript definitions for `window.OTPCredential` is not created yet, so you have to create it on your own.

Comment: @bogdanoff Could you please give me any kinda resource or way of how to do add typescript definitions please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73540310/1479798

Answer (score 1):

```
'use client'

import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'

type CredentialRequestOptions = {
  otp: OTPOptions
  signal: AbortSignal
}

type OTPOptions = {
  transport: string[]
}

const InputConfirmCode = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>()
  const hiddenOTPRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if ('OTPCredential' in window) {
      if (!hiddenOTPRef.current) return
      const ac = new AbortController()
      const o: CredentialRequestOptions = {
        otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
        signal: ac.signal,
      }
      navigator.credentials
        .get(o)
        .then((otp: any) => {
          if (hiddenOTPRef.current) {
            hiddenOTPRef.current.value = otp.code
            autoFill()
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err)
        })
    }
  }, [])

  const autoFill = () => {
    if (hiddenOTPRef.current && hiddenOTPRef.current.value.length === 5) {
      setValue(hiddenOTPRef.current.value)
    }
  }

  return (
    <input
      style={{ padding: '14px' }}
      type="hidden"
      value={value}
      autoComplete="one-time-code"
      inputMode="numeric"
      ref={hiddenOTPRef}
    />
  )
}

export default InputConfirmCode
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

since `window.OTPCredential` is just being used for checking whether device supports otp api, you can either add this

```js
// types.d.ts
declare global {
  export interface Window {
    OTPCredential?: any;
  }
}
export {};
```

or just ignore error (it will ignore next line only)

```js
// @ts-ignore
  if ('OTPCredential' in window) {
```